# Исправить регулярное выражения для выбора последних скобок

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Само регулярное выражение:

```
^(?<team>.*?)\s[(](?<param>.*?)[)]$
```

Регулярное выражение работает с таким форматом без проблем: `Франция  (-2.5)`

Сегодня пришел новый формат и программа его не понимает: `Франция (Пары) (-2.5)`

Как исправить? Нужно, чтобы в группу `param` попадала только информация из последних скобок, а если есть другие скобки они входили в `team`.

Answer (score 2):

Ваша первая группа помечена как ленивая, из-за этого в нее попадет всё до первой скобки, вам же нужна жадная группа — просто уберите `?`:

```
^(?<team>.*)\s[(](?<param>.*?)[)]$
```

ну а я бы переписал так:

```
^(?<team>.+)\s*\((?<param>.+)\)$
```

Comment: Спасибо. Очень помогли.

Answer (score -2):

```
@"^(?<team>.*[^\s])\s*\((?<param>.*?)\)$"
```

Вот так переписал регулярное выражение. Всем спасибо.